# create a new data frame after mutating

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new data frame after mutating values of second column of df1 and 2:4 rows.
so I want to subtract all values of df1[c(2:4),NCOL(df1)] with tax_v and create a new data frame dynamically.

```
df1 <- data.frame(t = c("77%","72%","74%","77%","79%"),
                  s = c("73%","74%","79%","74%","79%"))
tax_v = "74%"

new_col <- as.numeric(gsub("%","",c(df1[c(2:4),NCOL(df1)]))) %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(across(v1 = new_col[,1]-tax_v))
```

output should be like  a data frame

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
library(readr)

data.frame(calc = paste0(parse_number(df1[2:4, ncol(df1)]) - parse_number(tax_v), '%'))

#  calc
#1   0%
#2   5%
#3   0%
```

Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  slice(2:4) %>%
  select(last_col()) %>%
  mutate(s = paste0(parse_number(s) - parse_number(tax_v), '%'))
```

Comment: any dplyr solution ....?? so that i can modify in future if required

Comment: Updated the answer with a `dplyr` one.

Comment: One line option is better for me

Answer (score 0):

Using `ss` and `slt` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
slt(tfm(ss(df1, i = 2:4, j = 2), 
     calc = str_c(parse_number(s) - parse_number(tax_v), '%')), 2)
  calc
1   0%
2   5%
3   0%
```